# Rsnapshot: Don't run if NAS hasn't been mounted yet

Tags: mount

I'm running a raspi to backup some data to a usb flash drive.
Some of the input data is located on a nas and mounted as smb-drive.

After electrical power failure (which happens rarely), I'm facing following issue:

- Both, raspi and NAS, start directly after power-on
- NAS needs some time (1-2 Minutes) to be reachable in the network
- raspi is much faster and doesn't mount the NAS drive on power on

Consequently, the mountpoint remains empty and the calls to rnaspshot are saving empty data.
That's not a big problem, but: As soon as I manually mount the nas by means of `sudo mount -a` rsnapshot saves the nas data from scratch without re-using the existing data and that eats up the memory on my pen drive.

My basic idea is to wrap the cron-calls of rsnapshot (at least the hourly ones) into a bash script which checks whether the nas has been mounted. If not, it would try to mount if mounted, it would call rsnapshot.

Is this a proper approach to my issue or could you suggest a much cleaner solution?

Thanks

Comment: You say in your question, "I manually mount the nas by means of sudo mount -a ". Does that mean that you have not created an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount your NAS at boot time?

Comment: There is actually an entry in `/etc/fstab` but since the NAS is not ready in network at boot time, this doesn't mount the drive. Consequently, I've to manually do it afterwards.

Comment: Oh that shouldn't be! Could you add your `/etc/fstab` entry to your question? [This Q&A may have the answer to your problem.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount)

Comment: That's one line out of the `/etc/fstab`


`//192.168.21.22/raspi     /mnt/wdmycloud/raspi     cifs username=raspi,password=*****,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0744,dir_mode=0744`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I call rsnapshot by means of /etc/crontab with root rights, it's not a service as mentioned in the link. Do I still need to wrap the call to rsnapshot in order to wait for the mount?

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you running? If it's a recent one, I think you are using `systemd`, but just not aware of it. Try entering this from the CLI: `systemctl list-units --type=mount`

Comment: Raspian: Buster 
systemctl shows a line for each nas share e.g.:
mnt-wdmycloud-raspi.mount     loaded active mounted /mnt/wdmycloud/raspi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107039/discussion-between-seamus-and-amw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your situation:

1. You have a NAS drive mounted on your RPi. Let's assume that mount point is:

   `/mnt/wdmycloud/raspi`
2. You also mount a thumb drive on your RPi. Let's assume that mount point is:

   `/mnt/thumbdrv`
3. You have a script called `rsnapshot` that you have scheduled to run at regular intervals in a `cron` job. `rsnapshot` copies or backs up some data from the NAS drive to the Thumb drive. You wish to avoid performing copy/backup operations in `rsnapshot` when the NAS is not mounted as this causes issues. (I assume these issues are due to how your script is written, but that is speculation)
4. You occasionally have power outages that affect both the RPi and the NAS. The NAS has a longer boot time, and for reasons that aren't clear to me, the NAS is not being re-mounted by `systemd` once it has booted; this failure requires you manually `mount` the NAS following a power outage.
5. In summary then, it sounds as if you have two issues:

   - **Issue 1:** failure to mount the NAS after a power outage
   - **Issue 2:** dysfunction of `rsnapshot` due to NAS not being mounted

#### Issue 1:

The following may work to resolve Issue 1:

Schedule a re-mount of the NAS in root's `crontab`:

```bsh
sudo crontab -e           # use root's crontab instead of running sudo in yours
```

When the editor opens, add this line to root's `crontab`:

```
@reboot (sleep 120; mount -a -v >> /home/pi/yourlogfile.txt 2>&1)
```

This will cause `cron` to wait 2 minutes after it's started during the RPi boot cycle, and then mount everything in `/etc/fstab`. You can experiment with the `sleep` value if 2 minutes isn't quite right. This `cron` job will also send all `stdout`  and `stderr` output from the `mount` command to the log file. If the NAS drive is not being mounted, you will see that in the `stdout` output in this log file. If that `mount` fails, you will also (hopefully) see some useful `stderr` output that gives clues as to the cause of failure.

#### Issue 2:

The following may work to resolve Issue 2:

As you have suggested in your question, it is possible to determine whether or not the NAS is properly mounted prior to copy/backup operations. One way to do that is to use `findmnt` in your `rsnapshot` script. Without seeing the `rsnapshot` script, something like this may work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
...
# snippet for checking if NAS is mounted
if [[ $(findmnt -M "/mnt/wdmycloud/raspi") ]]
then
    echo "NAS Drive Mounted at /mnt/wdmycloud/raspi"
    # proceed with copy/backup operations
else
    echo "NAS Drive NOT mounted, Try Again Later"
    # wait, resolve, exit ??
fi
...
```

Refer to `man findmnt` for details on this command & its options.

As you think through this, there are several options available. For example, you could use `findmnt` in root's crontab (although elevated privileges are not required to use `findmnt`), and loop through `sleep` sessions until it became TRUE. Similarly, you may also wish to verify that your Thumb drive is mounted before going further in `rsnapshot`.

Let us know if this doesn't work & we'll try to help.

Comment: Does that `sleep` also block further crontab actions, in particular the hourly call of `rsnapshot`? If not, I'm afraid that the first rsnapshot call would happen exactly during the sleep time.

Comment: No - it doesn't block other jobs. But I think I've finally understood something in your question that I was missing earlier. I'm revising my answer now - give me a few minutes.

Comment: Works well bith both sultions. Thanks.